# Accessing a file in mercurial using revision/changeset ID (without doing a hg update)

Tags: mercurial

I have an application that needs to access multiple revisions of a file at the same time in the repository and check for contents.
How do I access the file version with my own application. Is there an API or hg command to pick the version.

Boundary condition being no hg update to be done.

[The mercurial invoked diff tools seem to do it using the path qualifiers of the form - @183:27bc9c60648d
But these path qualifiers do not work directly on the shell since the filesystem does not actually have such a file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally what you would do is use [`hg cat`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#cat) to retrieve the contents of a particular file at a particular revision, and then either pipe that to another command or dump it into a temporary file to operate on.

Comment: I would have liked to use some path qualifier to pick the file. But since mercurial does not store it in native form, I suppose generating a temporary copy and operating on it is necessary. Accepting the answer since it meets the need.

Comment: @Gns The difftols do check out the old files into a temporary directory with the @...-path appended. There is no filename access to files at other revisions, only in some tools it appears as such.